# How to search mulitple value seperated by commas in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to search multiple values separated by commas.

ex:

**table name : searchTest**

```
id    name      keyword

1     trophy1   test1,test2,test3

2     trophy2   test2,test5
```

Points:

1. If i search for test2 both results trophy1 and trophy2 should be display.
2. If i search for trophy1 then trophy1 should be as result.

How to solve this issue.

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean when you say Points: 1 .. 2. Do you need a single query to address both types of answers or two different once. Have you considered storing the data differently if you need both "points" to be addressed in the same query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like.

```
select * from searchTest where keyword like '%test2%'
```

Where the % is a wildcard.

Comment: Just a note : this will match a line containing something such as `test1,blahtest2glop,test3` ;;; i.e. it doesn't match only *full-tags*, but partial ones as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that, here, your data structure is quite not right.

It would be a better solution to not store several values in one field using some comma-separated format, but use three tables, defined this way :

- `searchtest`

  - `id`
  - `name`
- `keywords`

  - `id`
  - `word`
- `keywords_searchtest`

  - `id_keyword`
  - `id_searchtest`

With that, searching for entries in `searchtest` that have specific keywords would be as simple as :

```
select searchtest.*, keywords.*
from searchtest
    inner join keywords_searchtest on keywords_searchtest.id_searchtest = searchtest.id
    inner join keywords on keywords.id = keywords_searchtest.id_keyword
where keywords.word = 'test2'
```

And, additionnaly, you'd have to search for searchtest entries with a specific name :

```
select *
from searchtest
where name = 'trophy1'
```

Comment: Since this is ultimately going to be a search being driven by some input, the first query could be used to accomplish both searches by using an OR clause adding (not adjusted for coding language):  keywords.word = var OR searchtest.name = var

Comment: i agree with Etherton. Martin can you please explain what is the need of two queries.

Comment: @Fero : I actually agree with @Joel, in at least most cases ; the only situation where you'll need two queries is if a name doesn't have any keyword : the inner join will fail, in such situations, and return no line *(not tested, but this is what should happen)*

Comment: oh that's quite right Martin. I didn't think of it. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

These keywords must be stored in the separate table

Answer (score 1):

For Point 1 :
select * from searchTest where keyword like  LIKE '%test2%

For Point 2 :
select * from searchTest where name like  LIKE 'trophy1%

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) MySQL string function, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM searchTest WHERE FIND_IN_SET('test2', keyword) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from searchTest where keyword  LIKE 'test2' or LIKE '%,test2' or LIKE 'test2,%'
```

it will work  i have done this using above query

Comment: I think you probably meant to add '%' to your first `LIKE 'test2'` fragment. Probably 
LIKE '%,test2,%' or LIKE '%,test2' or LIKE 'test2,%'