# how to split a string field sentence in mysql to words

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a CMS for adding a new product. Along with adding the product I am giving an option to add keywords.

```
Keywords:<textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="keywords"></textarea>
```

Then it is inserted in to mysql table. But i want to use these keywords for a search option. Now it is saving as a string of sentences seperated by comma or space. How can I get each word back from the table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152137/mysql-string-split

Comment: WHERE keyword like '%<your_keyword_goes_in_here>%' ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749744/how-to-search-mulitple-value-seperated-by-commas-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can find functions that deals with string-splitting [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) and [here](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP method: explode($delimiter, $string).

Example:

```
$newArray = explode(' ', $yourPhraseWithSpaces);
```

or

```
$newArray = explode(',', $yourPhraseWithCommas);
```

Answer (score 0):

by using

```
array preg_split ( string $pattern , string $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int $flags = 0 ]] )
```

or

```
 explode($delimiter,$string)
```

or

```
  spliti ( string $pattern , string $string [, int $limit = -1 ] )
```

or

```
  chunk_split ( string $body [, int $chunklen = 76 [, string $end = "\r\n" ]] )
```

or

```
  str_split ( string $string [, int $split_length = 1 ] )
```